# Definition of increasing/decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, logic, definition

> $f$ is said to be strictly increasing $\iff \forall x,y \in D_f:x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)$

I haven't taken any mathematical logic classes yet so I don't know if it correct to write this as well:

$f$ is said to be strictly increasing $\iff$
$$ \forall x,y \in D_f:x \ne y, f(x)<f(y) \implies x<y$$

Is this correct? Would it make a difference if I wrote the $\forall$ at the end, instead of at the beginning?

Comment: The $x\ne y$ is redundant. The $\forall$ must be at the beginning.

Comment: In your version the premise and conclusion of the implication (arrow) have been switched. That does not in general mean the same thing.

Comment: @coffeemath but it does mean the same thing here.

Comment: It's correct but as pointed out the $x\ne y$ is not needed (but doesn't hurt) because it is impossible for $f(x) < f(y)$ if $x = y$.  It's like rewritten "a person is a fireman if her job is to put out fires" with "a person is a fireman if she is employed and her job is to put out fires".   It's not wrong but it is superflous.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is a constant function. It is then not strictly increasing. But your quantified conditional is true as the antecedent is always false.

Comment: By quantified conditional you mean: "$ \forall x,y \in D_f:x \ne y, f(x)<f(y) \implies x<y$ " ?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: But how is it true if $f$ is constant?

Comment: If $f$ is constant function, then for $a \neq b$, $f(a) < f(b)$ is false. Hence, using the truth table for the conditional, given $a \neq b$, $f(a) < f(b) \Rightarrow a < b$ is true. But $a, b$ were arbitrary, so the universal quantification is true too. [If that sounds mysterious, you should read Daniel Velleman's hugely useful book How to Prove It, designed exactly for people needing to know this stuff!]

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean $F \implies T$ is true. So my "definition" doesn't work then.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to specify $x \ne y$ as one of the hypotheses since that is implied by the fact that $x<y$ (or that $f(x)<f(y)$). However, one mistake you made is you wrote the [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_implication) of the implication, which is not equivalent to the original implication. Indeed, it's possible for a strictly increasing function to make the statement $\forall x,y \in D_f : f(x)<f(y) \implies x<y$ false, namely any function whose domain has one element.

In formal logical notation, all quantifiers must appear before the things they quantify, meaning that your $\forall x,y \in D_f$ must appear at the front.

That said, there is a widely understood convention in informal mathematical notation that front-loaded universal quantifiers can appear after a statement, in line with the way we often speak mathematics in English (e.g. "$x^2$ is nonnegative for all real values of $x$"). This is best avoided if you're trying to be formal, because you run into ambiguity when instances of quantifier alternation occur.